# Scan and lists of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

I am trying the following construction but I get an error message.

Let `l` be a list consisting of pairs of integers.

Let further `m` be a list consisting of a pair of positive integers. I want to do something like the following:

```
 Scan[(l[[1,#[1]]+l[[1,#[2]])^2,m]
```

That is, I want to for each list in `m`, add `l[[1,#[1]]` and `l[[1,#[2]]` together, and then take the square where # is the current list. I get the error message:

> Part::pkspec1: The expression #1[1] cannot be used as a part specification.

I suppose I am doing something illegal with the syntax. My question is:

Is there some better way to do this? Or how can I make this work?

Comment: whenever `#` shows up, there really should be a `&` somewhere along the way. I do not see `&` in your code?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of glitches, so it is difficult to infer exactly what you actually want to be doing. You'll get better answers if you can give  some sample values of $l$, $m$ and your desired output.   Still:

1) You need an ampersand `&` as Nasser commented.

2) You want to access the elements of the current list so you will use double brackets for list access, e.g. `#[[1]]` not passing arguments as to a function `#[1]`.

3) `Scan` has no footprint if its scanning function doesn't make an assignment or `Throw` an exception or `Sow` information.  You probably want to use `Map` so you can access the output.

4) Since `l` consists only of pairs, if you have the `m` elements access the second index, `m` can only have values of 1 or 2 or you will throw an error.  Since you said "positive integers" and not just 1 or 2, you may want to exchange the order of your indexing.

#### If $m$ list elements only contain values 1 or 2:

```
l = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {20, 2}]

(* Out: {{4, -1}, {4, 3}, {0, -2}, {1, 4}, {4, -4}, {-3, -2}, {-1, 1}, {4, 
  2}, {-3, -2}, {1, 5}, {2, -4}, {4, -4}, {0, 2}, {3, -4}, {1, 
  3}, {0, -3}, {0, 3}, {-2, 2}, {-3, 3}, {2, 3}} *)

 m= RandomInteger[{1, 2}, {20, 2}]

(* Out: {{2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 
  2}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 
  1}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}} *)

 Map[(l[[1, #[[1]]]] + l[[1, #[[2]]]])^2 &, m]
```

yields:

> {4, 4, 9, 9, 64, 9, 64, 4, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 64, 64, 9, 64, 9}

#### If the values of m can range over the length of $l$:

If $m$ can be as follows:

```
 m = RandomInteger[{1, Length[l]}, {Length[l], 2}]

(* Out: {{5, 14}, {3, 12}, {15, 4}, {8, 2}, {17, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 9}, {11, 
  15}, {5, 17}, {19, 1}, {19, 6}, {5, 14}, {14, 17}, {6, 17}, {12, 
  14}, {11, 2}, {9, 20}, {12, 2}, {15, 18}, {7, 2}} *)
```

you will need to change your indexing order. Why? A call of `Map[(l[[1, #[[1]]]] + l[[1, #[[2]]]])^2 &, m]` would result in error, since you're asking for e.g the 5th element of a 2 element list.  Maybe you meant:

```
Map[(l[[#[[1]], 1]] + l[[#[[2]], 1]])^2 &, m]
```

yielding:

> {49, 16, 4, 64, 16, 16, 9, 9, 16, 1, 36, 49, 9, 9, 49, 36, 1, 64, 1,
>     9}