# Scan and Set over multi-dimensional data

Tags: list-manipulation, assignment

Suppose I have the following:

```
Table[x[i,j] = f[i,j], {i,1,10},{j,1,10}];
```

I want to set variables `x[i,j]` to have value `f[i,j]` where `f` can be anything. The `Table` *(and you could also achieve this with a `Map` and I'm sure many other ways)* produces an undesirable list which will be discarded. This is a waste of memory, especially if `f` produces some large object, and the copies will have to be garbage collected even though I've suppressed the output.

To avoid this behaviour for lists I would normally do a `Scan` like this example in the documentation:

```
test = Scan[(u[#] = x) &, {55, 11, 77, 88}]
```

It sets `u[55], u[11], u[77], u[88]` without creating any intermediate lists and `test` is `Null`.

Compare this with a `Map` where `test` is populated with the values on the RHS of the `Set`. Also note this `test` return value is for illustrating the idea only and I expect to  discard it:

```
test = Map[Set[u[#],x] &, {55, 11, 77, 88}];
```

**Question:**

1. How can I use `Scan` over a multidimensional list such as `Tuples[Range[10],2]` to achieve the same effect as the `Table` example at the top of this question? I am not interested in using a `For` loop and I am only interested in achieving this with `Scan` if that's possible.
2. Are my fears about the discarded return values wasting memory and adding to garbage collection time justified if the object on the RHS of the `Set` is very large? Can *Mathematica* tell when a `Table` or `Map` is about to discard the list they build up and avoid creating one? *I suspect not e.g try* `MaxMemoryUsed[Table[x, 300000];]`

**Update:**

`Scan` appears to be consistently worse for memory usage, much to my surprise. Why? Surely it can't be because of the `Range` that must be constructed first, because `MaxMemoryUsed[Range[10000]]` is only 80376 bytes.

```
f[i_] := RandomReal[i, {64, 64}];
MaxMemoryUsed[Scan[(x[#] = f[#]) &, Range[10000]]]
ClearSystemCache[];
MaxMemoryUsed[Table[y[i] = f[i], {i, 10000}]]
ClearSystemCache[];
MaxMemoryUsed[Do[z[i] = f[i], {i, 10000}]]
ClearSystemCache[];
```

Comment: Note: a question with similar title appeared here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154609/scan-and-lists-of-lists but the OP didn't need a `Scan` to begin with and the answer doesn't even use a `Scan` so it's not that relevant.

Comment: `Do` can be thought of a as a drop-in replacement for `Table` when the list is not necessary.

Comment: @C.E. I know I can do it with `For`, `Do`, `While` etc.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but wouldn't something like this work? `(u[##] = f[##]) & @@@ {{4, 4}, {5, 2}, {4, 3}}` (The latter are just some random sample locants)

Comment: @MarcoB no because `test = (u[##] = f[##]) & @@@ {{4, 4}, {5, 2}, {4, 3}};` is not Null. It creates a list of results which needs to be garbage collected - which is fine if the items produced by `f` are small, but slow if they are large. This is not an XY problem, I'm _only_ interested in how to do it with `Scan` - I already know several other ways to achieve the same effect as the `Map` or `Table` approach.

Comment: @flinty I think the confusion arises in the fact that the `Table` and `Scan` options you show as examples are NOT equivalent, i.e. the `Table` will evaluate f and set ALL elements, but the `Scan` option will only set a few. So perhaps it's more a problem of the example you have in the question?

Comment: @MarcoB you could equally well do `test = Scan[(u[#] = x) &, Range[10]]` vs. `test = Table[Set[u[i],x] , {i,10}]` vs. `test = Map[Set[u[#],x]&, Range[10]]`. The `Table` and `Map` both produce lists because `Set` returns the value. However, `Scan` returns `Null`. If I don't put the results of the `Map` or `Table` into a variable `test` then I believe the results are being created & discarded. If I use `Scan` _(or a for/while/do loop but I know those already)_ I can avoid creating these hidden results. Important esp. if the thing on the rhs of the `Set` has a big memory footprint.

Comment: @MarcoB however, see my comment on C. E's answer, because it's possible _Mathematica_ might know how to recognize when the results are discarded as the memory usage is better for `Table` than `Scan`, even if `f` has a big footprint, e.g `f[i_,j_]:=RandomImage[1, {1024, 1024}] `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find `Scan` to be a strange solution to your problem since the input to `Scan` is a list of the same dimension that the output of `Table` would be, and a list like that is what you would like to avoid.

Here is how you would do it:

```
Scan[(x[Sequence @@ #] = f[Sequence @@ #]) &, Array[List, {10, 10}], {2}]
```

As I suggested in my comments, `Do` is a drop-in replacement for `Table` without the output, but I understand that this is not what you want.

Comment: The input list isn't important because it's just small indices. The output of `f` is why I need `Scan`. If you imagine f produces a lot of output, then the `Table[...];` will go and run all these f and set x for each one. But it will also return copies of those results of f in a big list which is discarded. `Scan` just returns `Null` and nothing was wasted.

Comment: @flinty Alright.

Comment: Weirdly though, I'm profiling both with `MaxMemoryUsed` and the `Table` does better than `Scan` - maybe _Mathematica_ knows when the Table isn't going to return its contents and doesn't bother creating a list that's going to be discarded anyway. I also tried with this `Scan[Set[Evaluate[x @@ #], f @@ #] &, Tuples[Range[10], 2]]`

Comment: @flinty Try using `MemoryInUse[]` instead of `MaxMemoryUsed[]`. I have had trouble interpreting the results of the latter in the past